# Merge Array on date to display Google Chart

Tags: php, arrays, charts, google-visualization

I'm stucked trying to "merge arrays on date" to display data into Google Column charts. I would like to group a list of problem and their cost by Year/Month. Here is my data

```
array 
  0 => 
    array
      'date' => string '2017-03' 
      'source' => string 'Problem 1'
      'cost' => float 135
  1 => 
    array
      'date' => string '2017-03'
      'source' => string 'Problem 2'
      'cost' => float 385
  2 => 
    array
      'date' => string '2017-04'
      'source' => string 'Problem 3'
      'cost' => float 3500
  3 => 
    array 
      'date' => string '2017-04'
      'source' => string 'Problem 1'
      'cost' => float 4437.5
  4 => 
    array
      'date' => string '2017-04'
      'source' => string 'Problem 2'
      'cost' => float 318
```

Where desired output would be https://jsfiddle.net/9d1fzsaf/1/

If got the data by MySQL groupby Date and problem source, maybe should I optimize the query?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(creation_date,'%Y-%m') AS date,
                ( CASE
                         WHEN source_problem = '0' THEN 'Empty'
                         WHEN source_problem = '1' THEN 'Problem 1'
                         WHEN source_problem = '2' THEN 'Problem 2'
                         WHEN source_problem = '3' THEN 'Problem 3'
                        ELSE 'Others'
                END ) AS source,
                            SUM(aprox_cost) AS cost
                        FROM table
                        WHERE source_problem IS NOT NULL
                        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(creation_date,'%Y-%m'),
                                 source_problem
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Regroup your data while fetching records from query.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, that's exactly what i'm trying to do
$req->execute();
    `$results = $req->fetchAll();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $data[] = array('date'=>$result['date'],'source'=>$result['source'], 'cost'=>(float)$result['cost']);
      }`
I don't know how to regroup data by date here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to produce the chart in the posted fiddle,
each `source_problem` will need to be a separate column

recommend separating the columns in the sql...

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(creation_date,'%Y-%m') AS Month,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN source_problem = '0'
    THEN aprox_cost
    ELSE 0
  END) AS Empty,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN source_problem = '1'
    THEN aprox_cost
    ELSE 0
  END) AS Problem1,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN source_problem = '2'
    THEN aprox_cost
    ELSE 0
  END) AS Problem2,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN source_problem = '3'
    THEN aprox_cost
    ELSE 0
  END) AS Problem3,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN source_problem <> '0' AND source_problem <> '1' AND source_problem <> '2' AND source_problem <> '3'
    THEN aprox_cost
    ELSE 0
  END) AS Others
FROM
  table
WHERE
  source_problem IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(creation_date,'%Y-%m')
```

also, when using JSON data, it needs to be in [this format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam),
in order to create the data table directly...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

as such, build results similar to following...

```
$data = array();

$data['cols'] = array(
  array('label' => 'Month', 'type' => 'string')
  array('label' => 'Empty', 'type' => 'number')
  array('label' => 'Problem 1', 'type' => 'number')
  array('label' => 'Problem 2', 'type' => 'number')
  array('label' => 'Problem 3', 'type' => 'number')
  array('label' => 'Others', 'type' => 'number')
);
$data['rows'] = array();

foreach ($results as $result) {
  $row = array(
    array('v' => (string) $result['Month'])
    array('v' => (float) $result['Empty'])
    array('v' => (float) $result['Problem1'])
    array('v' => (float) $result['Problem2'])
    array('v' => (float) $result['Problem3'])
    array('v' => (float) $result['Others'])
  );
  $data['rows'][] = array('c' => $row);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

**i have modified in your mysql query. please used this code**

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(creation_date,'%Y-%m') AS date,
                    ( CASE
                             WHEN source_problem = '0' THEN 'Empty'
                             WHEN source_problem = '1' THEN 'Problem 1'
                             WHEN source_problem = '2' THEN 'Problem 2'
                             WHEN source_problem = '3' THEN 'Problem 3'
                            ELSE 'Others'
                    END ) AS source,
                                SUM(aprox_cost) AS cost
                            FROM table
                            HAVING source_problem IS NOT NULL
                            GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this query gives an error
`#1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column`

Comment: I have modified in script.. can you check pls.

Comment: Still same error, actually the query is working my result look like
`date -- source_problem -- cost
2017-3 -- Problem 1  -- 100`
My problem is more how to make google charts consume the data